# Compressing/encoding SQL commands for faster network transmission

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, synchronization, icloud

I am developing an iOS app which stores its data in an sqlite3 database. Every insert, update or delete operation is logged locally and then pushed up to iCloud, and other devices running the app can download these transaction logs and execute the SQL commands within them to keep all devices running the app synchronised. This is working extremely well.

I am now looking into optimising the process and it occurs to me that logging the whole SQL command results in a lot of redundant data being pushed to and pulled from the cloud, which will ultimately result in longer sync times and increased data usage.

The SQL queries are very predictable (there is only one format each of insert, update and delete used in the app) so I am considering using an encoding/decoding routine which will compress the SQL command for storage in the transaction log, and then decompress it from the log for execution.

The string compression methods I have found don't seem to do too well with SQL queries, so I've devised my own:

- Single byte to identify the SQL command type
- Table and column names indexed in arrays in the app, and the names are encoded using their index position in the array
- String of tab separated digits to represent groups of columns, and tab separated values (e.g. in a VALUES() clause)
- Encoded check column and value (for the WHERE clause in an update or delete command)

Using this format I have compressed one example query of 186 bytes down to just 78 bytes. This has clear advantages for speed of data transmission and amount of data usage.

The disadvantage I foresee is that it will require more processing on the client end to encode and decode the commands. I am wondering whether anybody has done anything similar and has any advice to offer.

To make is clearer what I am asking: in general is it better to minimise the amount of data being synced and increase the burden on the client to interprete those data, or is it preferable to just sync the data as-is and leave the client to use it as-is?

Comment: Although you have achieved about 50% compression, the overall amount of data is fairly insignificant; of course this may just be your example, I have no idea how much data your app will need to sync. The other option is something like zip compression

Comment: @Paulw11 - thanks for your response. I hadn't considered using zip compression. There will be a lot of queries to sync, but the data values will be very small (e.g. updating a row from 0 to 1). That's why I had the idea of reducing the longest parts of the query (the SQL syntax itself and the table/column names) to the shortest values possible and sending only the variables themselves in their full format. Do you think that zipping the data would result in better compression since it would also compress the values being inserted/updated? I suppose I could do both to get even less data...

Comment: I don't know if zipping will give less, but it should be able to do 50% on reasonable amounts of text. The reason I thought of zip is that standard libraries are readily available so it is less coding

Comment: Given that most networks transmit data in packets, it is quite possible that even the reduction from 186 bytes to 78 bytes would do exactly nothing.  Both fit easily into a single typical packet.  I suspect you are over optimizing.

Comment: @Paulw11 - thank you I will look into the zip option.

Comment: @Gordon Lindoff - thank you for your reply. The commands will not be sent individually but will be appended to a file containing all previous commands, hence my desire to make them as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer to my own question because I have some information which may provide advice to others who are looking in to the same thing.

I spent some time yesterday writing SQL query compression and decompression functions in Objective C. These functions use the method detailed in my original question and in so doing reduce all non-data parts of the queries (SQL command [insert/update/delete], table names and column names) to a single digit to represent each, and remove all of the remaining SQL syntax (key words like "FROM", spaces, commas, brackets...).

I have done some testing by creating five records both with and without the query compression enabled, and here are the results for the file sizes:

**Full SQL queries** (logged unmodified to the transactions file)

- *Zip compressed:* 747 bytes
- *Uncompressed:* 1,515 bytes

**Compressed SQL queries** (compressed using my custom format to the transactions file)

- *Zip compressed:* 673 bytes
- *Uncompressed:* 785 bytes

As you can see, the greatest benefit was to using both types of compression. Encoding the queries achieved ~50% compression. Encoding and then zipping the queries achieved about 10% compression compared to zipping the unencoded queries.

The question I really need to ask myself now is whether it's worth the additional overhead to encode and then zip the queries, and unzip and decode them after downloading the transaction logs from other devices. In this example I only saved 74 bytes overall by encoding and then compressing the transaction log. With five queries this averages at 14.8 bytes saved per query (compared to zipping alone). This is just 14.4kb per 1000 records, which does not seem a lot.